# Bq aquaris m10 sms

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet

Is there a way to install [KDE Connect](https://community.kde.org/KDEConnect) for bq aquaris m10? 
Maybe there is a similar app /program like KDE Connect?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to control your tablet from your computer or control a phone from your tablet ? The M10 doesn't have a sim so can't SMS

Comment: I want to control my phone with the tablet (send and receive sms). That's why i wonder if there is a way to install kde connect on the tablet.

Answer (score 1):

So possibly you could create libertine container and compile the kde-connect software in there. I'm guessing it won't be in the repos since the M10 has an older version of ubuntu on it.

There are other options depending on your phone and what protocols it supports. You might be able to install https://wammu.eu/wammu/ in a libertine container via the repos and control your phone with it.

The other piece of software which could work for you is [gnokii](http://wiki.gnokii.org/index.php/Installation#Installation_via_package_manager) but I haven't used since I had an N810 and even then I had to write my own [frontend for it](http://www.softwareontheside.info/2011/11/more-texting-on-your-n810.html) but xgnokii might work on the M10. Again you'll probably have to install it in a libertine container.